# @RequestScoped @Named("base") Bean not initializing in JBoss EAP 7.0

Tags: cdi, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF api 2.2 specification Mojarra implementation with **JBoss EAP 7.0** server

```
@javax.inject.Named.Named("base")
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

but these annotations are not initializing my bean though

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name="base")
```

working perfectly even these are **Deprecated** in JSF 2.2

~Target Unreachable, identifier 'base' resolved to null, javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @10,78 listener="#{base.getData}"
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2584)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2114)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:287)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:299)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)

~

Comment: These 'new' annotations are CDI ones and not JSF or EJB... I changed the tagging for you. Start reading the links here: https://www.google.com/search?q=cdi+beans+not+found+site:stackoverflow.com and see which one helps. Most likely related to a beans.xml file

Comment: Post this error in the stackoverflow search field and start reading. Lots of good things t obe found. And deprecation !=removed... They will be removed in the next major JSF release (3.0)